# Break up a string on the first comma

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like so: `some where is something at something, I am, something` and I would like to use jquery to say - *on the first comma have break the string, remove the comma and place a carriage return* so that the string no looks like:

```
some where is something at something
I am, something
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what this have to do with jQuery? And the answer is yes; it is possible. But what have *you* tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var str = "some where is something at something, I am, something";
str = str.replace(',', '\r\n');
$("body").html(str);
```

Even though this isn't jQuery, it can be used with jQuery.  jQuery has no method for replacing parts of a string, so this is probably this quickest way to do it.

**Note:** This will not replace all occurences, only the first.  To replace all, do this:

```
var str = "some where is something at something, I am, something";
str = str.replace(/,/g, '\r\n');
$("body").html(str);
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I imagine it's because an answer is being given to a question that shows little effort.

Comment: Also, it appears that both answers have an incorrect solution, one that would replace all commas with newlines instead of only the first one...

Comment: @abiessu No, it wouldn't. It will only replace the first comma unless the `g` flag is specified in the regex (like `/,/g`).

Comment: Ah, function mixup on my part.  Nevermind then.

Comment: I also imagine someone is using  "strategic downvoting".

Answer (score 1):

Use String .replace() method. If the first parameter is a plain string, replacement happens once.

```
var str = 'some where is something at something, I am, something';
str = str.replace(',', '\n'); // or \r\n
```

If you want to replace all commas, use regular expression like:

```
var str = 'some where is something at something, I am, something';
str = str.replace(/,/g, '\n'); // or \r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "some where is something at something, I am, something "
var temp = myString.replace(",","\n");
alert("Temp is: " + temp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsQ5y/